# Il verbo "molestare" ha assunto un significato prevalentemente sessuale?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, history

Ascoltando le notizie in italiano di tanto in tanto, ultimamente ho avuto l'impressione che il verbo "molestare" si usasse soltanto con un significato sessuale (e praticamente sempre per dire "molestare una donna"). Infatti, ricercando "molestare" su Google, la prima entrata che ho trovato che non fosse un dizionario o simile (Reverso, bab.la, ecc.) è questa notizia: ["Roma, agente di polizia lasciava il lavoro per molestare una donna"](http://m.ilgiornale.it/news/roma/roma-agente-polizia-lasciava-lavoro-molestare-donna-1806101.html).

Tuttavia, cercando il vocabolo ["molestare" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI10/00000705.jpg) mi è sembrato capire che questo verbo possa avere altre accezioni. Infatti, nel mio lavoro, a volte succede che devo dire a un ragazzo (in catalano) qualcosa come "no molestis la teva companya" (il verbo "molestar" in catalano non ha questo significato sessuale) e sarei tentata di tradurlo come "non molestare la tua compagna". La mia domanda è: se dico questo a un ragazzo sarebbe interpretato come un'accusa di tentativo di abuso sessuale (forse non esattamente "abuso sessuale", ma quello che in inglese si chiama "sexual harassment")? In modo più generale, il verbo "molestare" e il sostantivo "molestia" hanno assunto ormai un significato prevalentemente sessuale mentre invece nel passato si usavano con altri significati?

Comment: Da quando le “molestie sessuali” hanno cominciato a ricevere la giusta attenzione pubblica il termine molestare viene spesso (purtroppo) usato in relazione a questi fatti.  - https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molestie_sessuali

Comment: @Gio:  Anche questa espressione, "molestia sessuale", attira la mia attenzione: a me sembra quasi un eufemismo. In catalano e in castigliano esiste anche la parola ["molestia"](https://dle.rae.es/molestia?m=form) ("molèstia" in catalano), ma non ha mai questo significato.

Comment: Potresti usare l’espressione “dare fastidio/infastidire” per evitare fraintendimenti. “Smettila di infastidire la tua compagna”.

Comment: @Gio:  E cosa significa l'avvertimento di Wikipedia: "Questa voce o sezione sull'argomento diritto ha un'ottica geograficamente limitata"?

Comment: ***Molestare***: 1. infastidire, disturbare: molestare i vicini con urla e schiamazzi, essere molestato dalle zanzare; anche ass.: rumori che molestano | ***importunare***  specialmente  con frasi e atteggiamenti sgradevoli e volgari: molestare una ragazza. (De Mauro)

Comment: Violenza e molestia sessuale: qual è la differenza?   https://www.laleggepertutti.it/173970_violenza-e-molestia-sessuale-qual-e-la-differenza

Comment: Questo grafico mostra come l’espressione “molestie sessuali” si sia diffusa dagli anni ‘80 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=molestie+sessuali&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmolestie%20sessuali%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Gio: Invece, vedi questo: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=molestie+sessuali%2Cmolestie&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmolestie%20sessuali%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmolestie%3B%2Cc0. Quindi, prima degli anni 80, "molestie" aveva un altro significato?

Comment: Come, per esempio, questo: https://books.google.es/books?id=cEFaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA28&dq=%22molestie%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihwOS9gobnAhUL3hoKHRLQDCoQ6AEwBHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22molestie%22&f=false

Comment: Il significato originale e anche attuale di molestia è quello di disturbo, fastidio in senso più generico. Ma da quando è stato adottato in senso giuridico, e con l'aumento delle denunce di molestie sessuali nei recenti decenni, il termine richiama alla mente episodi di carattere sessuale.

Comment: Se tu dici ad una amica “sono stata molestata” lei penserebbe subito ad una molestia sessuale.

Comment: @Charo: Non direi  che “molestie sessuali” sia un eufemismo: le “molestie” sono un reato ben preciso previsto dal codice penale, in cui, anche se non previste esplicitamente dal codice, rientrano quelle sessuali. Si tratta comunque di atti relativamente blandi (apprezzamenti, insistenze verbali etc.): qualunque contatto fisico rientra nella “violenza sessuale”.

Comment: @DaG: Probabilmente sono colta da un "falso amico" e penso a "molestia" col significato che ha nella mia lingua.

Comment: Hai ragione, @Charo: il senso generale di “molestia” e “molestare” sarebbe anche in italiano “dare fastidio” (un bambino che gioca vicino a uno che si concentra è molesto), ma di fatto questo uso quotidiano direi si stia perdendo, forse anche per via dell'uso in ambito giuridico. Ho inoltre l'impressione che molti abbiano le idee poche chiare e pensino, per esempio, che dare una pacca sul sedere (indesiderata) sia una molestia, mentre invece è un violenza, ben più grave.

Comment: Giusto per stare in argomento https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'amore_molesto_(romanzo)

Comment: Attenzione a giornali telegiornali e internet: spesso violentano l'Italiano perchè seguono mode stupide, o perchè vogliono condensare troppo, o perchè esagerano per colpire l'attenzione (di solito le tre cose insieme). Un esempio orribile: quando parlano di morti in un incidente, dicono vittime. E' sbagliato: una vittima non è un morto, è semplicemente qualcuno che subisce qualche cosa di spiacevole. Se in un incidente d'auto ci sono 2 morti e e 3 feriti, le vittime sono 5.